# How to add event to Google Calendar (2018 design) from Chrome omnibar?

Tags: google-calendar, google-chrome

In the old design of Google Calendar it used to be possible to add a new event directly from Chrome's omnibar using the following URL:

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/event?ctext=+%s+&action=TEMPLATE&pprop=HowCreated%3AQUICKADD
```

This URL is no longer working. Does someone know how to still use Chrome omnibar to create a quick event on Google Calendar?